# Extend Magento REST API in custom module and ACL allow

Tags: api, magento, rest, magento-1.8

I have created module with Rest API for that using following link

[Extending-the-Magento-REST-API](http://web.archive.org/web/20130512072025/http://magepim.com/news/Extending-the-Magento-REST-API-part-1_13)

When I run following URL `/api/rest/magepim/products/count` I get 403 error.

Deeper research of magento core code show that problem here

```
\app\code\core\Mage\Api2\Model\Server.php
```

string #216

```
   if (!$globalAcl->isAllowed($apiUser, $request->getResourceType(), $request->getOperation()))
```

What's wrong in example? I guess reason is missing or incorrect acl in xml files but where?

Magento version is 1.8

Answer (score 0):

Did you follow the below instructions?

In the admin, System->webservices->REST Roles-> Add administrator role.

Create a role as admin and  select the "MagePim API calls" from the Role API resources list.

Then In the Role users tabs, select the admin user (  by selecting "Any" in the dropdown and user list will be shown. From that select admin user and save.

Then try and let me know if any issues.